# Authorize user from database in c#

Tags: c#, role-base-authorization

I am working on a website in asp.net(C#) . I want to authorize every logged in user (restrict to open any web page which user has no rights). I have 2 tables users and roles in Sql Server from where I want to get role & then authorize that user.

Answer (score 1):

Since, users and roles have a many to many relationship, there would be another junction table between users and roles. Let's say it would be **UserRoles**

So, now on any request you will design a global filter/ handler which will do the following:

```
var user = Session["UserName"]; // getting logged in user
var role = // query that junction table **UserRoles** to get all the roles this current user has
```

Comment: I am neither using asp.net identity nor MVC, its a simple asp.net website. I am validating user by sql sp only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate user access using a stored procedure, you will need the following:

1) **extra table to store roles for users** - let's call it `UserXRole`

2) **a stored procedure** or a user defined function to get user roles or check if a user has a certain role. Something like the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UserHasRole
(
    @UserId INT,
    -- if you provide role name or code, an extra join with dbo.Role is required
    @RoleId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result BIT = (CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM dbo.UserXRole X
            WHERE X.UserId = @UserId AND X.RoleId = @RoleId) THEN 1 
        ELSE 0)

    RETURN @result        
END
```

The code obeys user defined functions restrictions, so you can change it to a function that returns BIT. If you suspect that authentication logic might get complicate in the future, leave it as stored procedure.

3) **Call the procedure** using current logged user identifier

Whenever you validate user authentication, I expect to place some information about logged user into the `Session` object.

Checking that the user must have a certain role in order to do something means calling the stored procedure with current user identifier (e.g. `Session["UserId"]`) and required role (`RoleId`).

Above approach should work, but it might lead to many calls to your database. A better approach would be:

1) **Cache all user roles on authentication** - when user is authenticated, stored all his/her roles in a list within the Session. E.g.:

```
Session["CurrentUserRoles"] = rolesFromDb.Select(r => r.RoleId).ToList();
```

2) **Checking if a user has a role** is done in memory only. E.g.:

```
bool hasSomeRole = (Session["CurrentUserRoles"] as IList<int>)?.Contains(someRoleId) ?? false;
```

As it is, the question is quite broad. Try one of the suggested solutions and come back with more targeted questions when you get stuck.